# How do I change the path so the geckodriver can be found?

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am very new in the space of programming. I've googled now for hours and reduced the errors but I am unable to fix the last one. Looks super simple but I dont get it.
I imported selenium trying to open up a webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1")

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"


*    C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Julian/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
  File "C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 7
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1")
                                                                                                 ^*
```

I don't really know how to communicate this problem so sorry in case of the bad description.

PS: Geckodriver is already in a variable path.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.get(url)` to open the page.

Another thing: if GeckDriver is on your path, you don't need to specify the `executable_path` option.

Answer (score 0):

The `r` before the path to the GeckoDriver always seems to work for me

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1")

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the geckodriver.exe at the end with a r before the string.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Julian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\geckodriver.exe')
```